# Why getting Permission Denied error while using mkdir with PHP on XAMPP Linux

Tags: php, linux, xampp

I'm using XAMPP on my CentOS server. I just wrote a simple file upload script with PHP but there is a problem using mkdir() function, because of the error below:

```
Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /opt/lampp/htdocs/script.php on line 10
```

Also I can not use move_uploaded_file, because of the same problem.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: show us line 10 in your script.php ...

Comment: Try to run the script with "sudo <your_script>"

Comment: Its because the server dont have the permissions to write for the path.

Comment: that's a simple mkdir() which creates upload folder beside the script if not exist.

Comment: Anyway, it's all about XAMPP... There should be a point about that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give permission to your web server or www folder  like this, here www-data is apache group and user, make sure you have one apache user and group.

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/webserver/www

chmod -R g+rw /path/to/webserver/www
```

In your case

```
chmod -R g+rw /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

Comment: but I think there is no www-data user and group exist on the server.

Comment: in XAMPP we have htdocs directory in this path: /opt/lampp/htdocs

Comment: It is an apache group and user, so all you have to do your files should have under apache group and user.

Comment: chown: invalid user: `www-data:www-data'

Comment: In that case use it `chmod -R g+rw /opt/lampp/htdocs` @JohnSmith

Comment: Ok, i will add more info to solution later if found any, for now that is my solution. Wait for more answers they might help you in this case.